# k2pdfopt reads only 3 pages?

Tags: linux, pdf

k2pdfopt reads only 3 pages?
I am trying to crop regions from different pages and concatenate them on output.pdf
But, k2pdfopt does not read more then the first 3 pages.

Maybe you could give useful commands examples?
Maybe matters the order of parameter and source.pdf?
Maybe i miss some very important parameter?

summarizing any command, and any file outputs only 3 pages instead of all , or 3 pages or 1 page. Originally file contains 26 pages

```
e@Latitude:~$ sudo /bin/k2pdfopt Mer.pdf -cboxu 0,0 -cbox1 0,5,8.3,5 -cbox3 0,8,8.3,1 -cbox3 0,1.5,8.3,1 -cbox5 0,0,8.3,5 -cbox6 0,11,8.3,1  -wrap- -col 1 -vb -2 -t- -f2p -3 -fc- -w 1s -h 1s -ocr- -o Con.pdf
     

k2pdfopt v2.53 (w/DjVuLibre,OCR) (c) 2021, GPLv3, http://willus.com
    Compiled Dec  7 2021 with Gnu C v11.2.0 for Linux on x64.

 a. Autostraighten (-as)                 o. Output name (-o)
 b. Bitmap type (-jpg,-png,-bpc)        oc. OCR (-ocr,-ocrvis,...)
bp. Break pages (-bp,-f2p)              om. Output margins (-om)
 c. Color/Negative output (-c, -neg)     p. Page range (-p)
co. Column detection (-col,-ch,...)     pd. Padding/Marking (-p[lrbt],-mc)
cs. Contrast/Sharpen (-cmax,-g,-s,-wt)   r. Right-to-left page scans (-r)
 d. Device selection (-dev,-h,-w,-dpi)  rt. Rotate source page (-sr)
ds. Document scale factor (-ds)          s. Special (-de,-evl,-gs)
 f. Fit to single column (-fc)          sm. Show marked source (-sm)
gt. Gap thresholds (-gt...)              u. Usage (command line opts)
 j. Justification (-j)                   v. Vertical spacing (-vb,-vs)
 l. Landscape mode (-ls)                 w. Wrap/Reflow text (-wrap,-ws)
 m. Margin to ignore (-m)                x. Exit on completion (-x)
mo. Mode (-mode)                        

Selected options:
   Mer.pdf    -cboxu 0,0 -cbox1 0,5,8.3,5 -cbox3 0,8,8.3,1 -cbox3 0,1.5,8.3,1 -cbox5
    0,0,8.3,5 -cbox6 0,11,8.3,1 -wrap- -col 1 -vb -2 -t- -f2p -3 -fc- -w 1s
    -h 1s -ocr- -o  Con.pdf

Enter option above (h=help, q=quit):
```

**Reading 3 pages from Mer.pdf ...**

Detecting document orientation ... Ghostscript found:  '/usr/bin/gs'
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 2 through 2.
Page 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 2 through 2.
Page 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 3 through 3.
Page 3
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 3 through 3.
Page 3
No rotation necessary.
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 1 through 1.
Page 1

SOURCE PAGE 1 of 3 (8.3 x 11.7 in) ... 0 pages saved
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 2 through 2.
Page 2
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 2 through 2.
Page 2

SOURCE PAGE 2 of 3 (8.3 x 11.7 in) ... 2 pages saved
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 3 through 3.
Page 3
GPL Ghostscript 9.55.0 (2021-09-27)
Copyright (C) 2021 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
This software is supplied under the GNU AGPLv3 and comes with NO WARRANTY:
see the file COPYING for details.
Processing pages 3 through 3.
Page 3

SOURCE PAGE 3 of 3 (8.3 x 11.7 in) ... 0 pages saved

3 pages written to Con.pdf (0.3 MB).

Total CPU time used: 6.74 s

Answer (score 0):

Checking carefully, I found that option `-p` does not work, either does not detect pages in the document, or prints 3-6 pages depending on other settings , i.e. the size of output ...

The solution was to reinstall **k2pdfopt**.
I downloaded it, pasted to `/bin folder`

```
sudo chmod 777 /bin/k2pdfopt
```